# What results in gaining XP, and is it affected by difficulty level?

Tags: dungeon-hearts

I've played a few games of Dungeon Hearts, but I've been struggling to make much progress, usually only lasting a few battles before I reach the limit of my moving circles around quickly skill. It's probably worth mentioning that I'm playing on PC; the control system is not the easiest thing to master with a mouse.

From the title screen I noticed that there was a store, which seemed to contain all sorts of useful things that could potentially help me in my quest to not suck at this game. However, I also noticed that after having played a few games, I'd only earned a pitiful amount of XP.

[image: In-game store screenshot]

This has left me wondering, what actions in the game lead to me gaining XP? Is this related to leveling-up my characters in game? Is XP gain affected by the difficulty level?

Comment: The game is quite stingy on XP rewards. When getting enough XP to get everything in the store costs over 1500 and the most you can get on a normal run is 24 XP, that's a lot of times going through the motions. Hard mode is less reliable to beat despite its higher yield and will actually take longer than a normal run. Your best bet to improve your chances is to decrease fatestream speed, increase multiplier, increase energy gain, and get the archer poison effect. Be willing to use your abilities to clear the stream when in trouble.

Comment: Another way to gain XP faster would be to do a lot of really short battles followed by a quick death as this would yield more XP/minute than doing a full run. The problem is that death is only really quick from full health later in the game so you're likely to spend too much time trying to die.

Answer (score 1):

XP Gain is based on the number of battles you completed, and there is a multiplier based on the difficulty you're playing (Easy: x0.5, Normal: x1.0, Hard: x1.5).

Comment: What about the XP gain in endless mode? Also, while your answer is accurate, could you include any source you might have used? It might be useful for other users not only to verify the authenticity of the information, but to also make them aware of other potential sources of information.

Comment: I'm guessing this is probably the creator of the game which would make this not once, but [twice](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115833/do-you-have-to-beat-the-game-in-one-sitting/115902#115902) that he has posted answers as an unregistered user. This would mean that there is no other helpful source referenced.